# Which Java thread pool executor to use to easily resize pool size?

Tags: java, spring, threadpoolexecutor

I need to run a big number of short-lived tasks. I use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for it, but I need to change min/max thread pool sizes automatically at runtime. How to do that?

I use external AtomicInteger variable now and increase it before submit and decrease it in lambda-callback. May I skip it somehow? Just use thread pool executor and don`t anything else?

I read many article and people don't recommend to do that, is my solution ok or can I simplify it? I use spring, may be I can use something from there?

Answer (score 2):

From [API doc of ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> (...) Most typically, core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon
>   construction, but they may also be changed dynamically using
>   setCorePoolSize(int) and setMaximumPoolSize(int).

So if it is really necessary to modify these parameters at runtime, instantiate a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and configure it as needed.

But before you should think twice if you need a dynamic thread pool. Usually, if your tasks are not bound to any other resources but CPU, it is disadvantageous to have much more threads than processors.

So why not use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` as approximate value?

Answer (score 1):

Now I think I understand your problem better. Given that description I think that having one ThreadPoolExecutor per worker is a good approach:

```
  // Worker 1 //
  int w1ThPoSize = 5; // Initially 5 threads are assigned to worker 1
  ThreadPoolExecutor w1ThPo = 
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(w1ThPoSize,
                           w1ThPoSize,
                           0, // No excess threads, so keep alive time is not relevant
                           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, // keep alive time is 0, so no relevant
                           new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

  // Sending a task for worker 1
  w1ThPo.execute(() -> { System.out.println("I'm running"); });

  // Resizing worker 1 thread pool 
  w1ThPoSize = 10;
  w1ThPo.setCorePoolSize(w1ThPoSize);
  w1ThPo.setMaximumPoolSize(w1ThPoSize);

  // (similar approach for remaining workers)

  // When done, remember to shutdown thread pools!
  w1ThPo.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it, you are asking the pool to create a new thread (increase the pool size) when the task starts, and asks it to shutdown a thread (decrease the pool size) when the task ends --please correct me if I misunderstood you!

It that's what you are doing I would consider dropping that approach and just '*let the pool be*'. Creating threads is not cheap, and I assume your task can reuse the same threads once and again (that's what pools are for). A good approach is to set the number of threads to the number of processors as isnot2bad suggests.

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys, let me describe it more detailed. I have f. e. 5 workers. Worker - is a logical unit of work. And my PM wants to have 4 threads of worker1, 3 threads of worker 2, and so on. And also he wants to have ability to change max number of threads for each worker at runtime.  So I thought to use 5 thread pools and adjust number of threads in each of them separately. How do  you think I may do it better? Thank you